# I don't understand why can't open() file correctly in Python 2.x

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
from os.path import exists

def confirm(file_name):
    while not exists(file_name):
        print "File doesn't exist."
        file_name = raw_input("File name: ")

from_file = raw_input("copy from: ")
confirm(from_file)
to_file = raw_input("copy to: ")
confirm(to_file)

with open(to_file, 'w')as f:
    f.write(open(from_file).read())
```

Output in Terminal

```
copy from: asd.txt
File doesn't exist.
File name: test.txt
copy to: dsa.txt
File doesn't exist.
File name: test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex17.py", line 17, in <module>
    f.write(open(from_file).read())
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ad.txt'
```

Why does it open the incorrect file?

How to fix it?

And when I do this:

```
   from_file = raw_input("copy from: ")
   while not exists(from_file):
       print "File doesn't exist."
       from_file = raw_input("File name: ")
```

It Works well.

I want to define a function for less code, but I get a problem.

Comment: See my answer below for a slight variation on your approach...

Comment: bro what is your objective with this code? you could remove 11 line (confirm(to_file)) because cant exists.

Comment: @Milor123 Thanks for your help, I just didn't know it before.

Comment: @DavidZemens I’m happy to help :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would modify the function to handle the `raw_input` internally, you can do something like this which will loop `while` the input is not an existing file, and will return the file's path if it *is* an existing file.

```
from os.path import exists

def getFileName(msg):
    file_name = raw_input(msg)
    while not exists(file_name):
        print "File {} doesn't exist. Try again!".format(file_name)
        file_name = raw_input(msg)
    return file_name

from_file = getFileName("copy from: ")
to_file = getFileName("copy to: ")

with open(to_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(open(from_file).read())
```

**NOTE** This assumes both files already exist. If your intent is to *create* the `to_file` at run-time, we need to make some modification. Let me know if that is the case...

Comment: Doesn't matter, since calls to `confirm` don't do anything with what would be returned.

Comment: Get **NOTE**. I wrote code in this way just because I didn't know it can create the file at run-time. Your answer inspires me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The changes to `file_name` you make inside of `confirm` do not affect the parameter you passed to that function.  You should return the final value of `file_name` in `confirm`, and have the caller assign that to the appropriate variable.

Comment: Actually I tried with return, I put `return file_name`vertically after `file_name = raw_input("File name: ")`, it still didn't work, so I tried to put it vertically with `While`, but it also didn't work.

Comment: @WillBeethoven: Did you put the `return file_name` _outside_ the `while` loop? Did you assign the filename returned from the `confirm` function call?

Comment: @ PM 2Ring Thank you very much! From now on, I understand how to use return.

Answer (score 1):

Remove line 11 (confirm(to_file)), the new file cant exists

i think that you could use this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('newfile.txt', 'w') as nf:
        nf.write(f.read())
```